# Debugging C++ template class in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, templates

I'm learning C++ and using VS C++ 2008 Express.

I have a simple project with 2 code files. 
One is for my Class and the other is "_tmain()".
My class file is using: template <typename T> code.

The program seems to run fine, but I can't step into my class file code in c++ view. I have to look at the assembly code.

I can step into _tmain() just fine, but when I try F11 to step into my class methods, there is "no source code available".

Any ideas on this one?

Thanks,
M3NTA7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you just forgot to active debug information (happens if you create an empty project).
This can (at least in VS2005) be activated via the Projects Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Generate Debug Info.

Comment: Thanks, I just looked and I've got Debug info set to YES and I can set break points in 'main()' but when I try to step into from one of those lines into my Class is where I can only view assembly.

Comment: Do you have the .pdb in the same directory? Have you verified you are debugging the current build?

Comment: You say you have debug info set to yes, but are you actually compiling in Debug configuration (i.e. with  optimizations disabled)? Class template methods are typically all `inline`, and are likely to be aggressively inlined when you compile with optimizations.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, That was it. I disabled the optimizations and then I could break into my C++ code.